# Telegram Bot inline query - what array to make query?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I have a problem with a Telegram inline query answer in PHP.
I'm using this code:

Class functions:

```
public function answerInlineQuery($inline_query_id, $results, $cache_time = null, $is_personal = false, $next_offset = null){
    $param = compact('inline_query_id', 'results', 'cache_time', 'is_personal', 'next_offset');
    return $this->sendRequest('answerInlineQuery', $param);
}

public function InlineQueryResultArticle($id, $title, $message_text, $parse_mode = null, $disable_web_page_preview = false, $url = null, $hide_url = false, $description = null, $thumb_url = null, $thumb_width = null, $thumb_height = null)
{
    $type = "article";
    $params = compact("type", "id", "title", "message_text", "parse_mode", "disable_web_page_preview", "url", "hide_url", "description", "thumb_url",
                      "thumb_width", "thumb_height");
    return json_encode($params);
}

private function sendRequest($method, $params)
{
    return json_decode(file_get_contents($this->baseURL . $method . '?' . http_build_query($params)), true);
}
```

*bot.php* file :

```
$t = new telegramBot("##########################");

$data = json_decode($_REQUEST['salam'], true);

//$_REQUEST['salam'] => This method is not the problem and returns JSON that is receive from the telegram server


$id1 = $t->InlineQueryResultArticle($data['inline_query']['id'], "onvan1111", "TeXte Message1");
$id2 = $t->InlineQueryResultArticle($data['inline_query']['id'], "onvan2222", "TeXte Message2", null, false, "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-6/512/Horizontal-type-mask-Tool-icon.png", false, "short");
$id3 = $t->InlineQueryResultArticle($data['inline_query']['id'], "onvan3333", "TeXte Message3");


$res = array($id1,$id2,$id3);

$t->answerInlineQuery($data['inline_query']['id'], $res);
```

When I send inline query in my robot I have this log from PHP:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org/bot#################/answerInlineQuery?inline_query_id=297302915958357271&amp;results=%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22article%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22297302915958357271%2F0%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22onvan1111%22%2C%22message_text%22%3A%22TeXte+Message1%22%2C%22parse_mode%22%3Anull%2C%22disable_web_page_preview%22%3Afalse%2C%22url%22%3Anull%2C%22hide_url%22%3Afalse%2C%22description%22%3Anull%2C%22thumb_url%22%3Anull%2C%22thumb_width%22%3Anull%2C%22thumb_height%22%3Anull%7D%5D&amp;is_personal=0): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

Where does my code have the problem?

Comment: Look at what the actual output of the URL you are calling is – it contains a readable error message.

Comment: @CBroe i check that but file_get_content line not have error...the error is from arrays ...please check my functions :(

Comment: No, I am not going to debug your stuff for you. You could f.e. simply call that same URL you are using in your browser, and see what the response is. (And yes, `file_get_contents` swallows the body content silently, if the response code indicates an error – but by passing an HTTP context with the appropriate option set, that can be changed as well.)

Comment: @CBroe ok...i check ...but i don't know the result most be how?please gave me an example for answer inline query

Comment: recheck it..the result of request is : `{"ok":true,"result":true}` bot noting show to user who type inline query ..

Comment: any body can help me ?

Comment: hi @mostafa, how can i send inlinequery? i have read documentation but still not get notice how to do it thx

Comment: @IIMNURDIANSYAH it so easy.just use answerInlineQuery Method and use a result array like inlineQuery result Article. example array : `Array(
 Array(
  type = "article"
  id = "123" //id Most be STRING
  title = "MyTitle"
  input_message_content = Array(
         message_text = "My Message Text"
        )
 )
)`. You most Convert this Array to Json and send it by reult parameter of answerInlineQueryResult Method.

Comment: hi @Mostafa thanks for your response, can i get your email? i want learn about telegram with you. thanks :)

Comment: @adeveloper is my telegram id and web site : [WebSite](http://t.elegram.ir)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the code problam :
result of `InlineQueryResultArticle` function most **not** be **json**
and `$res` at this line :

```
$t->answerInlineQuery($data['inline_query']['id'], $res);
```

most be **json** encode :)